# cellForRowAtIndexPath not showing Realm objects data

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, realm

I'm trying to use Realm to store user data when they create something. I know that Realm is saving the right data and I can access the certain data I need, i.e. the name I'm trying to display on a label in the custom cell.

My code for the view controller

```
class MeetupListViewController: ToolbarTabSuper, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {



@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var toolbarView: UIToolbar!


var realm: Realm!
lazy var results: Results<Meetup> = { self.realm.objects(Meetup).sorted("meetupName") }()
var meetups = [Meetup]()
var items: [String] = ["We", "Heart", "Swift"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationItem.title = "Meetup List"
    self.toolbarView.barTintColor = tabToolbarColor
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    return 60
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.results.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! MeetupCellTableViewCell
    let item = results[indexPath.row]
    cell.label?.text = item.meetupName
    return cell
}
```

My code for the custom cell

```
class MeetupCellTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

var meetupName = UILabel()
@IBOutlet var label: UILabel!

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    self.contentView.addSubview(meetupName)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

}

The reuse identified is set in the storyboard where I created the label with an image I want to use. It seems the cellForRowAtIndexPath function isn't even being called. Everything seems to be working from what I've looked online, but it's simply not showing up.

Comment: what is `self.results`, where do you populate it? Somewhere asynchronous?

Comment: everything is correct when looking on your code. Set a breakpoint inside cellForRowAtIndexPath in order to see if it is calling the function or nor, tell me then.

Comment: @luk2302 It's populated from a call to the realm instance. It's properly populated, I've printed the RMArray to check

Comment: @Anokrize set a breakpoint and nothing. so it looks like the function isn't even being called.

Comment: probably some asynchronous call!?

Comment: @luk2302 How would it managed to be asynchronous if it's all happening in the same view. Or is it that it's loaded but not in a persistent way. I've had asynchronous problems in the past when trying to get Core Data working, but I'm not exactly sure how it would happen with Realm.

Comment: Ok, then there is a problem with your tableview. Set breakpoints in the other functions and tell me if they are working as expected?

Comment: @anokrize it isn't called any of the relevant table view functions. The IBOutlet is properly connected from the storyboard, but I guess there's something else that isn't hooking up right

Comment: Show me the header of your class please

Comment: `class MeetupListViewController: ToolbarTabSuper, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    

    IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    IBOutlet weak var toolbarView: UIToolbar!

    
    var realm: Realm!
    lazy var results: Results<Meetup> = { self.realm.objects(Meetup).sorted("meetupName") }()`

Comment: looks like you are missing UITableViewController? Can you edit your question so that I can see it a bit better?

Comment: @anokrize well it's a table view in a particular view controller so I was simply using the delegate and data source to populate data in the table view

Comment: Ah I see. Try connections the outlet with the TableView functions. Like this tableView: tableView

Comment: Check out my answer and say me if that worked for you

Answer (score 2):

You should set the `delegate` and the `data source` to self in order to hook up the tableView with your functions if you are using them inside a `ViewController`.

It should look like that:

```
self.tableView.delegate = self
self.tableView.dataSource = self
```

Comment: am I missing something small or is this exactly what I have?

Comment: No look at the declaration after tableView(tableView: tableView).
That what you have is tableView(tableView: UITableView)

Comment: tried it, getting errors about the casting of the tableView 's in the functions

Comment: "use of undeclared type tableView"

Comment: The problem is definitely that you aren't populating your tableView outlet with the tableView functions.

Comment: Did you made any spelling mistakes? This is a typical error if it doesn't know about the variable in your case the outlet.

Comment: Consider changing the name of your outlet from tableView to something like myTableView and then change them in your functions.

Comment: That makes sense, but the code I'm using is based on what other people use, and works, when having a tableview in a view controller. Should it not be populated with the functions alongside the delegate and data source

Comment: Hmm I am not sure about it but there is a linking error somewhere, I will research it. Your tableView isn't hooked up with the functions.

Comment: I wasn't setting the delegate and the data source to self. Rookie mistake, not I'm dealing with custom cell problems, but it seems to be connecting the two

Comment: Breakpoints triggered. Different errors, but it seems to be populating